# python sort list of dictionary by a list of items

Tags: python

```
    sellers = ["amazon", "walmart", "Target", "CVS",  "Walgreens", "macys", "kohls"]

    data = [
        {
        "price": "21",
        "title": "Laura Geller Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick, Red Overfl",
        "seller": "kohls",
        },
        {
        "price": "21.00",
        "title": "Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream",
        "seller": "amazon"
        },
        {
            "price": "21.00",
            "title": "Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream",
            "seller": "macys"
        },
        {
            "price": "21.00",
            "title": "Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream",
            "seller": "walmart"
        }
    ]
```

Here is my data. I wants to sort my data by **seller** as per the above list.
Actual the list has to be dynamic.

Please have a look how can i achieve this.

Below is my

expecting result:

```
    [
        {
            "price": "21.00",
            "title": "Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream",
            "seller": "amazon"
        },
        {
            "price": "21.00",
            "title": "Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream",
            "seller": "walmart"
        },
        {
            "price": "21.00",
            "title": "Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream",
            "seller": "macys"
        },
        {
        "price": "21",
        "title": "Laura Geller Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick, Red Overfl",
        "seller": "kohls",
        }
    ]
```

Please have a look

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sorted()`

```
res = sorted(data, key=lambda x: sellers.index(x['seller']))

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'price': '21.00',
  'title': 'Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream',
  'seller': 'amazon'},
 {'price': '21.00',
  'title': 'Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream',
  'seller': 'walmart'},
 {'price': '21.00',
  'title': 'Laura Geller Beauty Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick - Cream',
  'seller': 'macys'},
 {'price': '21',
  'title': 'Laura Geller Iconic Baked Sculpting Lipstick, Red Overfl',
  'seller': 'kohls'}]
```